# How to execute or view a .res file produced by a Fortran program?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have a code written in fortran saved as "DIET.F"

After I entered `$ g77 DIET.F` a file named "a.out" was created in the same directory as DIET.F.

After `$ /a.out` an output file called "126idi.res" was created.

What command do I give next so that I can run 126idi.res?

I am not even certain if my question makes complete sense, this is the first time I am using Fortran and I just need DIET.F to give me the output result in the terminal.

EDIT: the 126idi.res seems to be a binary file.

EDIT: DIET.F contains the following code:

```
    PROGRAM DIET

5   COMMON C(14,14,16)

    COMMON/CMN1/KAPPA,OMOM,MY,L2F(18)

    COMMON/KL/E(560),KV(560,2)

    COMMON/NUCL/Z,A,NUC,KIND

    COMMON/CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    COMMON/PTR/F(57)

C   PROGRAM CJ WRITTEN BY B.S.NILSSON

C   KIND=0 FOR NEUTRONS, 1 FOR PROTONS

C   PRESENT OUTPUT VERSION FOR AT MOST SN=10 AND MAXIMUM 50 LEVELS

    INTEGER Z,A,NUC

    REAL KAPPA,MY,LL

    EXTERNAL CLEBI

    DATA NUC/'OS'/

c       OPEN(UNIT=5,FILE='in.out',STATUS='UNKNOWN') 

    OPEN(UNIT=6,FILE='126idi.res',STATUS='UNKNOWN')

    EPS1=0.

    EPS3=0.

    EPS5=0.

    EPS6=0.

    F(1)=1. 

    DO 101 I=1,56

101 F(I+1)=F(I)*FLOAT(I)*.1

    DO 102 I=1,14

*   PRINT*,I

    DO 103 J=1,14

C   TYPE*,J

    LMIN=1

    LMED=1

    LMAX=1

    DO 104 K=1,3

C   TYPE*,K

    LMIN=LMIN+2*K-1

    LMED=LMED+2*K

    LMAX=LMAX+2*K+1

    M=4*K

C   TYPE*,LMIN,LMAX,LMED

    DO 105 LM=LMIN,LMAX

    V1=CLEBI(2*(I-1),M,2*(I-1-2*(LMED-LM)),2*(J-1),0,2*(J-1))

    V2=CLEBI(2*(I-1),M,2*(I-1-2*(LMED-LM)),0,0,0)

C   TYPE1212,V1,V2

1212    FORMAT(' V1=',E15.6,' V2=',E15.6)

    C(I,J,LM)=V1*V2*.1

105 CONTINUE

104 CONTINUE

    C(I,J,1)=0.

103 CONTINUE

102 CONTINUE

    L2F(1)=0

    DO 106 I=1,17

106 L2F(I+1)=L2F(I)+I+1

200 CONTINUE

        NS=10

        KAPPA=0.0668

        MY=0.575

        KIND=1

201 CONTINUE

        NUC=I

        Z=53

        A=126

        EPS2=0.142

        EPS4=-0.007

        LL=5.2

        UL=7.5

C   PRINT STATEMENT SADDED BY JAC10/76

    WRITE(6,500)NS,KAPPA,MY,KIND

C   TYPE500,NS,KAPPA,MY,KIND

500 FORMAT(5X,5HNS=  ,I5,10X,8HKAPPA=  ,F6.4,10X,5HMY=  ,F6.4,10X,

     1  7HKIND=  ,I3)

    WRITE(6,501)A,NUC,Z,EPS2,EPS4,LL,UL

C   TYPE501,A,NUC,Z,EPS2,EPS4,LL,UL

501 FORMAT(5X,10HNUCLEUS=  ,I3,A2,10X,4HZ=  ,I3,10X,7HEPS2=  ,F10.3,/

     1  10X,7HEPS4=  ,F10.3,10X,5HLL=  ,F10.3,10X,5HUL=  ,F10.3)

    IF(Z)200,203,202

202 CONTINUE

    WRITE(6,11)A,NUC

C   TYPE11,A,NUC

11  FORMAT(1H1,5X,21HC>J-COEFFICIENTS OF  ,I3,A2)

    CALL ENCJF(NS,LL,UL,FE)

    IF(KIND.EQ.0)WRITE(6,12)A,NUC

C   IF(KIND.EQ.0)TYPE12,A,NUC

    IF(KIND.EQ.1)WRITE(6,17)A,NUC

C   IF(KIND.EQ.1)TYPE17,A,NUC

12  FORMAT(1H1,//,6X,19HNEUTRON LEVELS OF  ,I3,A2)

C   TYPE*,A,NUC

17  FORMAT(1H1,//,6X,18HPROTON LEVELS OF  ,I3,A2)

    WRITE(6,13)KAPPA,MY,EPS2,EPS4

C   TYPE13,KAPPA,MY,EPS2,EPS4

13  FORMAT(/,6X,'KAPPA=',F6.4,4X,'MY=',F5.3,4X,5HEPS2=,F6.3,4X

     1  ,5HEPS4=,F6.3)

    WRITE(6,14)

C   TYPE14

14  FORMAT(/////,7X,18HENERGY Q.NUMB.    ,4(9X,15HENERGY Q.NUMB. ),/)

    DO 20 I=1,45

    I45=I+45

    I90=I+90

    I135=I+135

    I180=I+180

    WRITE(6,15)I,E(I),KV(I,1),KV(I,2),I45,E(I45),KV(I45,1),KV(I45,2)

     1  ,I90,E(I90),KV(I90,1),KV(I90,2),I135,E(I135),KV(I135,1)

     2  ,KV(I135,2),I180,E(I180),KV(I180,1),KV(I180,2)

C   TYPE15,I,E(I),KV(I,1),KV(I,2),I45,E(I45),KV(I45,1),KV(I45,2)

C    1  ,I90,E(I90),KV(I90,1),KV(I90,2),I135,E(I135),KV(I135,1)

C    2  ,KV(I135,2),I180,E(I180),KV(I180,1),KV(I180,2)

15  FORMAT(I4,F9.3,I4,2H/2,A2,4(I7,F9.3,I4,2H/2,A2))

20  CONTINUE

    WRITE(6,16)FE

C   TYPE16,FE

16  FORMAT('ALL ENERGIES IN MEV, 1 OSCILLATOR UNITIS',F7.4,4HMEV )

        EMMN=LL*FE

        EMMX=UL*FE

        WRITE(6,901)EMMN,EMMX

901     FORMAT('ENERGY LIMITS FOR WAVE FUNCTION PRINT',2F9.3)     

C   GOTO 201

203 CONTINUE

    CLOSE(UNIT=6)

    STOP

    END

C   ******************************************************

c       Original program only 5,6 

C   ******************************************************

    SUBROUTINE CJP(OMEGA,MORD,W)

C   CALCULATES CJ-COEFFIIENTS,DECOUPLING PARAMETER AND MATRIX

C   1ELEMENTS OF J-

C   BETWEEN ALL POSSIBLE LEVELS

    DIMENSION W(56,56),C(14),C2(14),IN(25),CF(80,11,11),COR(14)

    COMMON /E/ NYS,IQ,I,K,LEV,LEV1,LEV2,LEV3

    COMMON /KL/ EV(560),KV(560,2)

    DO 20 N=1,25

20  IN(N)=N

    LE=LEV2-LEV1

    NYS=NYS+1

    WRITE(6,10) LEV,KV(IQ,1),KV(IQ,2),EV(IQ)

C   TYPE 10, LEV,KV(IQ,1),KV(IQ,2),EV(IQ)

10  FORMAT(///,6X,8HLEVEL NO,I3,I5,2H/2,A4,6HENERGY,F8.2,4H MEV)

    WRITE(6,11)

C   TYPE 11

11  FORMAT(/,6X,'WAVE FUNTION')

    WRITE(6,12) (W(N,I),N=1,MORD)

C   TYPE 12, (W(N,I),N=1,MORD)

 12 FORMAT(10F11.5)

    NL=IFIX(2.*OMEGA)

    K21=2*K+1

    WRITE(6,13) (IN(N),N=NL,K21,2)

C   TYPE 13, (IN(N),N=NL,K21,2)

13  FORMAT(/,'  N  J%',I2,2H/2,10(6X,I2,2H/2))

    DO 21 N=1,14

    C(N)=0.

    COR(N)=0.

21  C2(N)=0.

    NN=0

    N=K

22  CONTINUE

    DO  31 MM=1,2

    RM=0.5-FLOAT(MM-1)

    IF(OMEGA-RM.GT.FLOAT(N)+0.1) GOTO 32

    LAM=IFIX(OMEGA-RM)

    L=N

    DO 34 LL=1,100

    NN=NN+1

    RJ=FLOAT(L)+0.5

    IJ=IFIX(2.*RJ)

    MI=IFIX(2.*RM)

    MOM=IFIX(2.*OMEGA)

    IF(ABS(W(NN,I)).LT.1.E-16) W(NN,I)=0.0

    CLE=CLEBI(2*L,1,IJ,2*LAM,MI,MOM)

    IF(ABS(CLE).LT.1.E-16) CLE=0.0

    C(L+1)=C(L+1)+W(NN,I)*CLE*0.3162278

    RJ=RJ-1.

    IJ=IFIX(2.*RJ)

    IF(RJ) 340,340,35

35  IF(ABS(W(NN,I)). LT.1.E-16)  W(NN,I)=0.0

    CLE=CLEBI(2*L,1,IJ,2*LAM,MI,MOM)

    IF(ABS(CLE).LT.1.E-16) CLE=0.0

    C(L)=C(L)+W(NN,I)*CLE*0.3162278

340 L=L-2

    IF(L.LT.LAM) GO TO 33

34  CONTINUE

33  CONTINUE

32  CONTINUE

31  CONTINUE

    IOM=IFIX(OMEGA+0.5)

    NLIM=N+1

    DO 36 J=IOM,NLIM

    IF(ABS(C(J)).LT.1.E-16) C(J)=0.

    CF(LEV,J,NLIM)=C(J)

    IF(LE) 360,360,37

37  DO 38 IJ=1,LE

    LI=IJ+LEV1

38  COR(IJ)=COR(IJ)+C(J)*CF(LI,J,NLIM)*SQRT(FLOAT(J*J-(IOM-1)**2))

360 IF(OMEGA-1.) 361,361,36

361 LEM=LEV-LEV3

    DO 362 IJ=1,LEM

    SIG=1.

    IF(MOD(J,2).NE.0) SIG=-1.

    LI=LEV3+IJ

362 COR(IJ)=COR(IJ)+C(J)*CF(LI,J,NLIM)*FLOAT(J)*SIG

36  C2(J)=C2(J)+C(J)*C(J)

    WRITE(6,14) N,(C(J),J=IOM,NLIM)

C   TYPE 14,N,(C(J),J=IOM,NLIM)

14  FORMAT(I4,F11.4,10(F10.4))

    DO 39 IJ=1,14

39  C(IJ)=0.

    N=N-2

    IF(N.GE.IOM-1) GO TO22

    K1=K+1

    WRITE(6,15) (C2(J),J=IOM,K1)

C   TYPE 15, (C2(J),J=IOM,K1)

15  FORMAT(5H  C2J,11(F10.4))

    IF(OMEGA-1.) 40,40,43

40  DEC=-COR(LEM)

    LEMM=LEM-1

    IF(LEMM.LE.0) GO TO 411

    DO 41IJ=1,LEMM

    LI=IJ+LEV3

    WRITE(6,18) LI,LEV,COR(IJ)

C   TYPE 18, LI,LEV,COR(IJ)

41  CONTINUE

411 WRITE(6,16) DEC

C   TYPE 16, DEC

 16 FORMAT(6X,17HDECOUPLING FACTOR,F10.4)

    RETURN

43  IF(LE) 44,44,45

44  WRITE(6,17)

C   TYPE 17

17  FORMAT(/////)

    RETURN

45  DO 46 IJ=1,LE

    LI=IJ+LEV1

    WRITE(6,18) LI,LEV,COR(IJ)

C   TYPE 18, LI,LEV,COR(IJ)

18  FORMAT(40H  MATRIX ELEMENT OF J- BETWEEN LEVELS NO,I4,

     +  ' AND',I4,'IS',F10.4)

46  CONTINUE

    RETURN

    END

C   ************************************************************

    SUBROUTINE ENCJF(SN,LL,UL,F)

    INTEGER SN,Q,ORD1,ORD2,ORD,Z,A

    REAL LL,OMEGA,M,M1,M2, KAPPA,MY

    DIMENSION M(56,56),M1(14,14),M2(14,14),E(56),KVH(2),W(56,56)

    COMMON /CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    COMMON /E/NYS,IQ,I,K,LEV,LEV1,LEV2,LEV3

    COMMON/KL/EV(560),KV(560,2)

    COMMON /CMN1/KAPPA,OMOM,MY,L2F(18)

    COMMON/NUCL/ Z,A,NUC,KIND

    DATA KVH/'+   ',' -  '/

    CALL OME(10,OMOM,1.0E-6)

    LEV=0

    LEV1=0

    LEV2=0

    LEV3=0

    Q=0

    ORD1=((SN+4)*SN+4)/4

    NYS=0

    FF=2.-FLOAT(Z)/FLOAT(A)

    IF(KIND.EQ.1) FF=1.+FLOAT(Z)/FLOAT(A)

    F=41.*FLOAT(A)**(-0.333333)*OMOM*FF*0.666667

    IO2MX=2*SN+1

        DO 201 IO2=1,IO2MX,2

    OMEGA=.5*FLOAT(IO2)

    DO 203 KK=1,2

    K=SN+1-KK

    IF(K.LT.IFIX(OMEGA-0.4)) GOTO 219

    DO 204 I=1,ORD1

    DO 205 J=I,ORD1

    M(J,I)=0.

    M(I,J)=0.

205 CONTINUE

204 CONTINUE

    CALL DM(K,OMEGA,M1,ORD1)

    ORD2=0

    DO  206 I=1,ORD1

    DO 207 J=I,ORD1

    M(I,J)=M1(I,J)

207 M(J,I)=M(I,J)

206 CONTINUE

    NNMX=((IFIX(OMEGA-0.4)-(K-2))/(-2)+1)

    IF(NNMX.LT.1) GOTO 209

    DO 208 NN=1,NNMX

    N=K-2*NN

    CALL DM(N,OMEGA,M1,ORD)

    CALL IDM(N,OMEGA,M2)

    DO 300 J=1,ORD

    JO=ORD1+J

    IOR2=ORD+2

    DO 301 I=1,IOR2

    IO=ORD2+I

    M(JO,IO)=M2(I,J)

301 M(IO,JO)=M2(I,J)

    DO 302 I=1,J

    IO=ORD1+I

    M(IO,JO)=M1(I,J)

302 M(JO,IO)=M1(I,J)

300 CONTINUE

    ORD2=ORD1

    ORD1=ORD1+ORD

208 CONTINUE

209 CONTINUE

    CALL JACOB(M,W,ORD1,1.E-6)

    DO 400 I=1,ORD1

    E(I)=F*M(I,I)

    IQ=I+Q

    EV(IQ)=E(I)

    KV(IQ,1)=IFIX(2.*OMEGA)

    KV(IQ,2)=KVH(1)

    IF(MOD(K,2).NE.0) KV(IQ,2)=KVH(2)

    IF(E(I).LT.LL*F.OR.E(I).GT.UL*F) GO TO 402

    LEV=LEV+1

401 IF(NYS.NE.3) GOTO 403

    WRITE(6,10) A,NUC

C   TYPE 10, A,NUC

10  FORMAT(//,5X,21HC>J-COEFFICIENTS OF  ,I3,A2,10H    >CCNT.,//)

    NYS=0

403 CALL CJP(OMEGA,ORD1,W)

402 CONTINUE

400 CONTINUE

    LEV1=LEV2

    LEV2=LEV3

    LEV3=LEV

    Q=Q+ORD1

203 CONTINUE

219 CONTINUE

201 CONTINUE

    CALL SORT2I(EV,KV,Q)

    RETURN

    END

C   *****************************************************************

    SUBROUTINE SORT2I(X,KV,N)

    DIMENSION X(560),KV(560,2)

    INTEGER Y1,AY2

    ID=2**INT(1.4427*ALOG(FLOAT(N-1)))-1

1   IF(ID.LE.0) RETURN

    I=1

2   J=I

    IPD=I+ID

    Y=X(IPD)

    Y1=KV(IPD,1)

    Y2=KV(IPD,2)











3   IF(Y.LT.X(J)) GO TO 4

5   JPD=J+ID

    X(JPD)=Y

    KV(JPD,1)=Y1

    KV(JPD,2)=Y2

    I=I+1

    IF(I+ID.LE.N) GO TO 2

    ID=(ID-1)/2

    GOTO 1

4   JPD=J+ID

    X(JPD)=X(J)

    KV(JPD,1)=KV(J,1)

    KV(JPD,2)=KV(J,2)

    J=J-ID

    IF(J.GE.1) GO TO 3

    GO TO 5

    END

C   *********************************************************

    FUNCTION   T(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)

    COMMON C(14,14,16)

    COMMON/CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    REAL MP,M

    T=0.0

    IF(LAMP.NE.LAM) RETURN

    IF  (MOD(LP-L,2) .NE.0) RETURN

    IF(IABS(LP-L).GT.6) RETURN

    X=FLOAT(N)

    Y=FLOAT(L)

    Z=FLOAT(LP)

    I=(LP-L)/2

    I7=I+7

    I13=I+13

    E6=-C(L+1,LAM+1,I13)*EPS6

    IF(IABS(I).LE.2) E4=C(L+1,LAM+1,I7)*EPS4

    I=I+4

    W=(Y+Y+1.)/(Z+Z+1.)

    GO TO (436,434,431,433,432,435,437),I

431 T=SQRT(W*(X-Y+4.0)*(X-Y+2.0)  )*0.5*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

432 T=SQRT(W*(X+Y+3.0)*(X+Y+5.0) )*0.5*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

433 T=SQRT(W*(X-Y+2.0)*(X+Y+3.0) )*0.5*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

434     T=SQRT(W*(X-Y+6.0)*(X-Y+4.0)*(X-Y+2.0)/(X+Y+1.0) )*0.5*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

435 T=SQRT(W*(X-Y     )/(X+Y+7.0)/(X+Y+5.0)/(X+Y+3.0)  )*0.5*(E4-E6)

     +   *(X*(X+4.0*Y+15.0)+Y*FLOAT(7*L+45)+71.)

    RETURN

436 T=-SQRT(W*(X-Y+8.0)*(X-Y+6.0)*(X-Y+4.0)*(X-Y+2.0)/(X+Y+1.0)

     +   /(X+Y-1.0) )*0.5*E6

    RETURN

437 T=-SQRT(W*(X-Y   )*(X-Y-2.0)/(X+Y+9.0)/(X+Y+7.0)/(X+Y+5.0)

     +   /(X+Y+3.0) )*0.5*(X*(X+6.0*Y+26.0)+Y*(17.0*Y+134.0)+258.0)*E6

    RETURN

    END

C   ************************************************************************

    SUBROUTINE IDM(N,OMEGA,S)

    INTEGER N

    REAL OMEGA

    DIMENSION S(14,14)

    INTEGER LP,LAMP,L,LAM,I,J

    REAL MP,M

    I=0

    DO 311 MMP=1,2

    MP=0.5+FLOAT (MMP-1)*(-1.0)

    IF(OMEGA-MP .GT.FLOAT(N+2)  + 0.1) GO TO 319

    LAMP=IFIX(OMEGA-MP)

    LP=N+2

    DO 312 LLP=1,1000

    I=I+1

    J=0

    DO 313 MM =1,2

    M=0.5+FLOAT(MM-1)*(-1.0)

    IF (OMEGA-M.GT.FLOAT(N)  +0.1) GO TO 318

    LAM=IFIX(OMEGA-M)

    L=N

    DO 314 LL=1,1000

    J=J+1

    S(I,J)=T(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)

    L=L-2

    IF(L  .LT.LAM) GO TO 315

314 CONTINUE

315 CONTINUE

318 CONTINUE

313 CONTINUE

    LP=LP-2

    IF(LP.LT.LAMP) GO TO 316

312 CONTINUE

316 CONTINUE

319 CONTINUE

311 CONTINUE

    RETURN

    END

C   *****************************************************

    FUNCTION U(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)

    COMMON C(14,14,16)

    COMMON/CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    REAL MP,M

    U=0.0

    IF(LAMP.NE.LAM) RETURN

    IF(MOD(LP-L,2).NE.0) RETURN

    IF(IABS(LP-L).GT.6) RETURN

    X=FLOAT(N)

    Y=FLOAT(L)

    Z=FLOAT(LP)

    I=(LP-L)/2

    I3=I+3

    I7=I+7

    I13=I+13

    E6=-C(L+1,LAM+1,I13)*EPS6

    IF(IABS(I).LE.2) E4=C(L+1,LAM+1,I7)*EPS4

    IF(IABS(I).LE.1) E2=(2.0/3.0)*C(L+1,LAM+1,I3)*EPS2

    I=I+4

    GO TO (406,404,401,403,402,405,407),I

401 U=-SQRT(  (X-Y+2.0)*(X+Y+1.0)*(Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)  )*(E2-E4+E6)

    RETURN

402 U=-SQRT(  (X-Y   )*(X+Y+3.0)*(Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)  )*(E2-E4+E6)

    RETURN

403 U=-(X+1.5)*SQRT(             (Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0) )*(E2-E4+E6)

    RETURN

404 U=SQRT(  (Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)*(X-Y+4.0)*(X-Y+2.0)

     +   /(X+Y-1.0)/(X+Y+1.0))*(X+Y+Y-1.5)*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

405 U=SQRT( (Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)*(X-Y   )*(X-Y-2.0)

     +   /(X+Y+3.0)/(X+Y+5.0))*(X+Y+Y+6.5)*(E4-E6)

    RETURN

406 U=-SQRT( (Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)*(X-Y+6.0)*(X-Y+4.0)*(X-Y+2.0)

     +  /(X+Y+1.0)/(X+Y-1.0)/(X+Y-3.0))*(X+3.0*Y-6.0)*E6

    RETURN

407 U=-SQRT( (Y+Y+1.0)/(Z+Z+1.0)*(X-Y  )*(X-Y-2.0)*(X-Y-4.0)

     +    /(X+Y+7.0)/(X+Y+5.0)/(X+Y+3.0))*(X+3.0*Y+12.0)*E6

    RETURN

    END

C   *******************************************************************

    SUBROUTINE OME(NNN,OMOM,NYI)

    COMMON/CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    REAL NYI,NY

    INTEGER T

    REAL I

    EXTERNAL F1

    NY=NYI

    T=NNN

    GO TO 332

331 T=2*T

332 CALL SIMPS(-1.0,1.0,T,F1,NY,I,IFLAG,0)

    IF(IFLAG.NE.0) GO TO 331

    OMOM=(0.5*I/(1.0+EPS2/3.0)/SQRT(1.0-2.0*EPS2/3.0))**(.3333333)

    RETURN

    END

C   ***************************************************:

    FUNCTION R2(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)

    REAL MP,M

    IF( (LP.NE.L).OR.(LAMP.NE.LAM)) GO TO 421

    R2=FLOAT(L*(L+1))

    RETURN

421 R2=0

    RETURN

    END

C   *************************************************

    FUNCTION F1(XI)

    COMMON/CMN2/EPS1,EPS2,EPS3,EPS4,EPS5,EPS6

    X=XI

2   AMN=(((((28.875*EPS6*X+15.75*EPS5)*X+(EPS4*8.75-39.375*EPS6))*X

     +   +(5.0*EPS3-17.5*EPS5))*X+(13.125*EPS6-7.5*EPS4-EPS2))*X+

     +    (EPS1*2.0-3.0*EPS3+3.75*EPS5))*X+1.0+EPS2/3.0+0.75*EPS4

     +   -0.625*EPS6

    F1=AMN**(-1.5)

    RETURN

    END

C   ***************************************************

    SUBROUTINE DM(N,OMEGA,R,ORD)

    INTEGER N,ORD

    REAL OMEGA

    DIMENSION R(14,14)

    INTEGER LP,LAMP,L,LAM,I,J

    REAL MP,M

    COMMON/CMN1/KAPPA,OMOM,MY,L2F(18)

    REAL KAPPA,MY

    I=0

    DO 301 MMP=1,2

    MP=0.5+FLOAT(MMP-1)*(-1.0)

    IF(OMEGA-MP .GT.FLOAT(N) + 0.1) GO TO 309

    LAMP=IFIX(OMEGA-MP)

    LP=N

    DO 302 LLP=1,1000

    I=I+1

    J=0

    DO 303 MM=1,2

    M=0.5+FLOAT(MM-1)*(-1.0)

    IF(OMEGA-M.GT.FLOAT(N)+0.1) GO TO 308

    LAM=IFIX(OMEGA-M)

    L=N

    DO 304 LL=1,1000

    J=J+1

    IF(J-I) 201,200,200

200     R(I,J)=U(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)-KAPPA/OMOM*(2.0*

     +    RS(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)+MY*R2(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M))

    R(J,I)=R(I,J)

    IF(I .EQ.J) R(I,J)=R(I,J)  +1.5+KAPPA/OMOM*MY*FLOAT(L2F(N+1))

     +     +FLOAT(N)

201 L=L-2

    IF (L .LT.LAM) GO TO 305

304 CONTINUE

305 CONTINUE

308 CONTINUE

303 CONTINUE

    LP=LP-2

    IF(LP.LT.LAMP) GO TO 306

302 CONTINUE

306 CONTINUE

309 CONTINUE

301 CONTINUE

    ORD=I

    RETURN

    END

C   *****************************************************

    FUNCTION RS(N,LP,LAMP,MP,L,LAM,M)

    REAL MP,M

    IF((L.NE.LP).OR.(LAM.NE.LAMP)) GO TO 411

    RS=FLOAT(LAM)*M

    RETURN

411 IF((L.NE.LP).OR.(LAMP.NE.LAM-1)) GO TO412

    RS=SQRT(FLOAT((L+LAM)*(L-LAM+1)))/2.0

    RETURN

412 IF((L.NE.LP).OR.(LAMP.NE.LAM+1)) GO TO413

    RS=SQRT(FLOAT((L-LAM)*(L+LAM+1)))/2.0

    RETURN

413 RS=0.0

    RETURN

    END

C   *************************************************************

    FUNCTION CLEBI(I1,I2,I3,N1,N2,N3)

    COMMON/PTR/ FCT(57)

    INTEGER  Z,ZMIN,ZMAX

    J1=I1

    J2=I2

    J=I3

    N=57

    M1=N1

    M2=N2

    M=-N3

    CC=0.0

    JSUM=J1+J2+J

    JM1=J1-IABS(M1)

    JM1=J1-IABS(M1)

    JM2=J2-IABS(M2)

    JM3=J-IABS(M)

    IF((MOD(JSUM,2).NE.0).OR.(MOD(JM1,2).NE.0).OR.(MOD(JM2,2).NE.0)

     +  .OR.(MOD(JM3,2).NE.0).OR.(JM1.LT.0).OR.(JM2.LT.0).OR.(JM3.LT.0))

     +   GO TO 1

    IF((M1+M2+M.NE.0).OR.(J.GT.J1+J2).OR.(J.LT.IABS(J1-J2))) GO TO 1

    ZMIN=0

    IF(J-J2+M1.LT.0) ZMIN=-J+J2-M1

    IF(J-J1-M2+ZMIN.LT.0) ZMIN=-J+J1+M2

    ZMAX=J1+J2-J

    IF(J2+M2-ZMAX.LT.0) ZMAX=J2+M2

    IF(J1-M1-ZMAX.LT.0) ZMAX=J1-M1

    JA=(J1+M1)/2+1

    JB=JA-M1

    JC=(J2+M2)/2+1

    JD=JC-M2

    JE=(J +M)/2+1

    JF=JE-M

    JG=(J1+J2-J)/2+1

    JH=JA+JB-JG

    JI=JC+JD-JG

    JJ=JE+JF+JG-1

    IF(JJ.GT.N) GO TO 5

    IA=ZMIN/2

    IB=JG-IA+1

    IC=JB-IA+1

    ID=JC-IA+1

    IE=JA-JG+IA

    IF=JD-JG+IA

    FASE=1.0

    IF(MOD(IA,2).EQ.0) FASE=-FASE

    Z=ZMIN

2   IA=IA+1

    IB=IB-1

    IC=IC-1

    ID=ID-1

    IE=IE+1

    IF=IF+1

    FASE=-FASE

    CC=CC+FASE/(FCT(IA)*FCT(IB)*FCT(IC)*FCT(ID)*FCT(IE)*FCT(IF))

    Z=Z+2

    IF(Z.LE.ZMAX) GO TO 2

    FASE=SIGN(1.0,CC)

    CC=FASE*SQRT(CC*FCT(JA)*FCT(JB)*FCT(JC)*FCT(JD)*FCT(JE)*CC*

     +  FCT(JF)*FCT(JG)*FCT(JH)*FCT(JI)/FCT(JJ)*FLOAT(J+1))

   1    CLEBI=CC

    RETURN

C 3 WRITE>6,4

C 4 FORMAT>26H0 ERROR IN ARGUMENT OF VCC

C   GO TO 7

  5 WRITE(6,6)

  6     FORMAT(' ERROR -FACTORIALS EXCEEDED')

  7 WRITE(6,8)I1,I2,I3,N1,N2,N3

C   TYPE 8,I1,I2,I3,N1,N2,N3

  8 FORMAT(10I10)

    RETURN

    END

C   ******************************************************

    SUBROUTINE SIMPS  (A,B,NI,F,NY,I,IFLAG,ISW)

C   IF >ISW.EQ.0 ,RETURNS.IFLAG%>1 IF TOLERANCE NOT MET,0 IF MET

C   IF>ISW.NE.0,ITERATES UNTIL TOLERANCE MET.IFLAG IGNORED.

    EXTERNAL F

    REAL NY,I

    REAL H,S1,S2,S3,I1,I2

    N=NI

    H=(B-A)/4.0/FLOAT(N)

    I2=F(B)-F(A)

    I1=I2

    S3=0.0

    S2=S3

    S1=S2

    N4=4*N

    DO 442 IP=4,N4,4

    S1=S1+F(A+H*FLOAT(IP-2))

    S2=S2+F(A+H*FLOAT(IP-4))

442 CONTINUE

441 CONTINUE

    DO 443 IP=2,N4,2

    S3=S3+F(A+H*FLOAT(IP-1))

443 CONTINUE

    I1=(I1+4.0*S1+2.0*S2)*H/1.5

    I2=(I2+4.0*S3+2.0*S1+2.0*S2)*H/3.0

    N=N*2

    N4=4*N

    H=H/2.0

    IF  (ABS(I1-I2) .LE.NY) GO TO 444

    I2=F(B)-F(A)

    I1=I2

    S2=S1+S2

    S1=S3

    S3=0.0

    IFLAG=1

    IF (ISW.EQ.0) RETURN

    GO TO 441

444 I=(16.0*I2-I1)/15.0

    IFLAG=0

    RETURN

    END

C   ************************************************



    SUBROUTINE JACOB(A,S,N,RHO)

C



C         JACOBI DIAGONALISATION

    DIMENSION A(56,56),S(56,56)

    INTEGER P,Q,Q1

    REAL INT1,NORM1,MU,NORM2

    DO 1 I=1,N

    I1=I-1

    DO 2 J=1,I1

    S(I,J)=0.0

2       S(J,I)=0.0

1   S(I,I)=1.0

    IF(N-1) 11,10,11

11  INT1=0.0

    DO 3 I=2,N

    I1=I-1

    DO 3 J=1,I1

    IF(ABS(A(I,J)).LT.1.E-16) A(I,J)=0.0

3   INT1=INT1+2.0*A(I,J)*A(I,J)

    IF(INT1-RHO)10,12,12

12  NORM1=SQRT(INT1)

    NORM2=(RHO/FLOAT(N))*NORM1

    THR=NORM1

    IND=0

4   THR=THR/FLOAT(N)

5   DO 6 Q=2,N

    Q1=Q-1

    DO 6 P=1,Q1

    IF(ABS(A(P,Q))-THR) 6,13,13

13  IND=1

    V1=A(P,P)

    V2=A(P,Q)

    IF(ABS(V2).LT.1.E-16) V2=0.0

    V3=A(Q,Q)

    MU=0.5*(V1-V3)

    IF(MU) 14,15,15

15  SGN=1.0

    GO TO 16

14  SGN=-1.0

16  OMEGA=-SGN*V2/SQRT(V2*V2+MU*MU)

    SK=SQRT ( 1.0-OMEGA*OMEGA )

    SINT=OMEGA/SQRT(2.0*(1.0+SK  ) )

    COST=SQRT(1.0-SINT*SINT)

    DO 7 I=1,N

    AIP=A(I,P)

    IF(ABS(AIP).LT.1.E-16) AIP=0.

    AIQ=A(I,Q)

    IF(ABS(AIQ).LT.1.E-16) AIQ=0.

    INT1=AIP*COST-AIQ*SINT

    A(I,Q)=AIP*SINT+AIQ*COST

    A(I,P)=INT1

    AIP=S(I,P)

    IF(ABS(AIP).LT.1.E-16) AIP=0.

    AIQ=S(I,Q)

    IF(ABS(AIQ).LT.1.E-16) AIQ=0.

    INT1=AIP*COST-AIQ*SINT

    S(I,Q)=AIP*SINT+AIQ*COST

7   S(I,P)=INT1

    DO 8 I=1,N

    A(P,I)=A(I,P)

8   A(Q,I)=A(I,Q)

    A(P,P)=V1*COST*COST+V3*SINT*SINT-2.0*V2*SINT*COST

    A(Q,Q)=V1*SINT*SINT+V3*COST*COST+2.0*V2*SINT*COST

    A(P,Q)=(V1-V3)*SINT*COST+V2*(COST*COST-SINT*SINT)

    A(Q,P)=A(P,Q)

6   CONTINUE

    IF(IND-1) 17,9,17

17  IND=0

    GO TO 5

9   IF(THR-NORM2) 10,10,4

10  RETURN

    END
```

Comment: Do not use version tags alone on this site, always use the generic tag (`fortran` in this case) and the version (`fortran77`) only if the question is version specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diet.f` contains a source code for the program. It contains all commands in human-readable format. After `g77`'ing it, you got an `a.out` which is the same program, but in machine-readable format. This one you can actually execute (run) and it performed something for you. It seems that it has produced a `126.res` file.

As the program was meant to perform something, it may turn out that all you are interested in sits in that `res` file. Try opening it in some program like notepad, vim, nano, mcedit, hexview or whatever general purpose editor. Look what's inside that file. If it is a text file, you will notice it and then simply read what's inside. Probably some results or error messages. Otherwise, you will see mess of strange characters. If this happens, then most probably the `res` file was some intermediate thing needed by the program. In this case, at least I can't tell you much more without seeing the DIET.F file and checking what it is supposed to do and how. Others probably won't be able to tell you much more.

To help others in answering you, please try to improve your question with some details:
- describe where did you get the DIET.F file so others can look at it, or attach it to the question
- tell us how did you exactly run the `a.out` program (have you passed any parameters or configuration?)
- tell us what the program has written to the screen, if anything
- you might also attach that .res file, or at least some first lines/blocks of it

By the way, where did you get an idea of "running the 126idi.res" from? was it described somewhere in the documentation of DIET.F ?

BTW2. if you don't have any viewer/editor like vim or nano or notepad, you can try writing out the res file to the terminal by: `cat 126idi.res` or `type 126idi.res`, but if it is not a text file, this can sometimes deadlock your terminal, so.. better check it with some fileviewer.

Comment: This code was given to me by my professor, and during his briefing he got an output (simulation) on his terminal. Which is why I tried to run the .res file.
Upon opening .res using geddit, I just see random garbage chinese characters.
I have uploaded the DIET.F code, hopefully that will help clarify the issue.

Comment: @DhruvDharamshi: how did you check the RES file to be binary? from the program's code, it seems to me that it should be a text file. All the `write` commands write to stream number 6th = res file, and they write text and numbers.. And what did the simulation look like? was it tons of text and descriptions written to the terminal? or was it graphical?

Comment: The simulation was columns of data (text). Not graphical.
When I go to the file location and right click > Properties; it says the file type  is "Binary (application/octet-stream)".

Comment: @DhruvDharamshi: This one does not always detect the file's contents properly. If you are working on Linux or similar system, open a **new terminal**, go to the path where RES file is located and type `cat 126idi.res`.  If the terminal displays trash and then locks up, just close it. If working on windows, you may check in new console window by `type 126idi.res` similarly. Both on Linux and on windows, if you have any text editor, try opening it and then try forcing it to open that RES file. For example, on windows, run Notepad and drag and drop the file onto notepad window.